# How to cancel a dialog when its theme is transparent?

Tags: android, dialog

```
Pls see the code below..



 final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this);
  mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); //it works

  mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
  mDialog.show();
```

But if i add theme for dialog then

```
      final Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
  mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); //But here It is not workin
      mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
  mDialog.show();
```

popup.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/lyt_popup"
 android:layout_gravity="center"
 android:background="@drawable/popup_background"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/play_game"      android:id="@+id/btn_play" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="96dp" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">   </Button>
  <Button android:background="@drawable/memory_game" android:id="@+id/btn_memory"   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  a   ndroid:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></Button>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: transparent means what you need to do

Comment: see edit..im displaying a layout and i need background is transparent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar works if you want the dialog to be full screen. An alternative is to create your own style, like so:

```
<style
    name="Theme_Dialog_Translucent"
    parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Below is the working code::

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.ThemeDialogCustom);
mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); //But here It is not workin
mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
mDialog.show();
```

have style.xml in values folder like below:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
<style name="ThemeDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
   </style>

</resources>
```

also add colors.xml in values folder:::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="transparent_color">#00000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: You can use system transparent color: `<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);` //But here It is not workin ,

It should be `mDialog.setCancelable(true);`

Comment: mDialog.setCancelable(true); this will work for only for BACK button